# Routing To A Folder In Cakephp's App/Webroot

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm aware that there are a few questions on this subject already.  I've trawled through them and can't make any of the proposed solutions work for me... maybe someone can help my specific problem?

I have a folder, parallax, in my app/webroot, containing index.html and associated files.  This can be accessed just fine at /parallax/.  However, if I try to access it at /parallax I get redirected to /app/webroot/parallax/, and ideally I'd like to suppress this behaviour.

Refactoring the whole thing as a CakePHP controller action isn't ideally something I want to get into (though if it might be simpler than I expect, let me know).  The routes file doesn't as far as I know allow routing to a file in app/webroot.

The other port of call would seem to be the .htaccess file.  I tried adding a rewrite rule:

```
RewritRule ^parallax$ parallax/index.html
```

or variations thereof, but the best I can get here is a page with broken images (whatever I'm ending up with, it doesn't seem to be able to find the images in the parallax/images subfolder any more).

Can anyone clear up my confusion and help me find the best route to /parallax giving the same result as /parallax/ does?

Comment: I'm not sure what parallax is, but maybe it could go into your app with the pages controller?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Okay, but wouldn't that necessitate reworking the whole thing as a view and a controller action, moving all the image and the js files new homes, etc etc?  That clearly can be done with a bit of time and effort, I'm just wondering if you can drop a folder of html, image and javascript files into app/webroot and access it in a hassle-free way without having to fully refactor into CakePHP every time.  Am I missing the point in some terrible way?

Comment: Not at all, it depends how complicated the files are. See if the [PagesController](http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller) will do it for you.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Okay, the pages controller looks interesting and potentially useful.  Problem is if I dump the contents of parallax into views/pages, I still have a bunch of images and js files that now don't link correctly, and need to be dealt with.  Might be an avenue for me to explore further though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the situation but its working corretly for me. I'm using cakePhp 1.3 and both urls send me to index.html:

```
http://localhost:5013/parallax/
http://localhost:5013/parallax
```

My guess is that there's something weird on your .htaccess (the one located at /app/webroot/). Mine is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically, it tells the server that if the requested url is not a file (!-f) nor a directory (!-d), it will redirect the whole url as a parameter to /webroot/index.php , so cakephp will parse the url and call the controllers and all that..

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm, my webroot .htaccess does contain all those lines, so someone has added a bunch of other RewriteRules (for very specific paths) between RewriteEngine On and the first RewriteCond.  I don't know if having rules before conds could be messing it up somehow?  In either case, it looks like adding a rewrite rule for parallax above the conds here can turn parallax into parallax/, which will do the trick at a pinch, so pointing me in this direction definitely has helped!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below .htaccess code in your root directory not in app directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   Rewriterule ^parallax/.*$ - [PT]
   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This should help you. What ever request start with parallax will be skipped by the .htaccess rule. And rest of the things will work as it is.

Comment: I think that works for, e.g., parallax/index.html, but I'm not sure it works for plain /parallax?

Comment: It wouldn't work for /parallax as without a / on the end it will look for a *file* named parallax

Comment: But this worked for me, I've used this to place my phpmyadmin folder in the server.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess root thanks to Anh Pham for this link it works perfectly http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-redirect-appwebrootblog-into-blog-wordpress-cakephp/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the parallax folder with a static index.html inside the app/webroot folder and have it be accessible by default at the /parallax/ url.

If you use relative paths you can even have you img/css for that page local to the folder and skip the usual cakephp paths entirely. No htaccess needed.

Comment: /parallax/ does work, but /parallax doesn't (well, it does, but it shows the full /app/webroot/ path for the url).  Maybe I was just asking too much.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have your apache virtualHost's webroot set to /<path>/<to>/app/webroot and have it instead pointed to the /app folder or the root folder instead. If your path is set correctly you should never see the /app/webroot part of the path in the address bar.

Comment: Did you try to set the webroot to app/webroot instead of app or the root folder?